Supabase (PostgreSQL) brain teaser
I have a 3 tables:

services - info about services (id, title)
city - info about city (id, city_name)
service_city - map multiple cities to services (service_id, city_id)

and I need functionality to select only those services which contain certain city provided by user.
So far I have got is solution below:
const cityToSearch = {
    id: 1,
    city_name: 'Amsterdam'
}

let query = supabase
    .from('service')
    .select('title, city(id,city_name)'
    )

if (search) query.ilike('title', `%${search}%`);
if (city) {
    query.eq('city.id', cityToSearch.id);
    query.not('city', 'is', null);
}

query.range(from, to);
const { data, error } = await query;

The problem is it returns me array of cities with only one city that I search for:
[
  {
    title: 'Service 1',
    id: 'service_1',
    city: [ 
      {
        id: 1,
        city_name: 'Amsterdam'
      } 
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Service 2',
    id: 'service_2',
    city: [ 
      {
        id: 1,
        city_name: 'Amsterdam'
      } 
    ],
  }
]

however, I need an array of cities that include my cityToSearch (ex.):
[
  {
    title: 'Service 1',
    id: 'service_1',
    city: [ 
      {
        id: 1,
        city_name: 'Amsterdam'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        city_name: 'Paris'
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    title: 'Service 2',
    id: 'service_2',
    city: [ 
      {
        id: 1,
        city_name: 'Amsterdam'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        city_name: 'Krakow'
      }
    ],
  }
]

Supabase documentation: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript
Any ideas? : )
